# Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) for beginners

Tags: wcf

I need to learn WCF for my project as I am building a client-server application under Windows. What's the best place to start. I've googled for tutorials and books but I couldn't find something suitable for starters. I would prefer a book.

Answer (score 1):

As for resoures: there's the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf) which has everything from beginner's tutorials to articles and sample code.

Also, check out the [screen cast library up on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx) for some really useful, 10-15 minute chunks of information on just about any topic related to WCF you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [PluralSight videos](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=wcf-fundamentals&highlight=aaron-skonnard_introducing-wcf*9#introducing-wcf) may be its easy way for you to start. [Some of the videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) are on MSDN for free.

Find book for yourself. For example [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735645566) could be easy to understand for beginner.

Look at [WCF samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd728058). Some samples can help you in learning.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a good book, check out [Programming WCF Services, 3rd Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805494.do) by Juval Lowy.

Other WCF book recommendations are listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386801/wcf-book-recommendations) question.